# How to apply slicing to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have around 500,000 entries in my dataframe, and I'd like to apply some kind of smoothing to this data in order to significantly decrease the amount of entries.

This is a sample dataframe `df`:

```
EVENT   GRADE   SERVICE_TIME   QUEUE_TIME   HOLD_TIME
AAA     3       170            20           12
AAA     4       165            15           10
AAA     3       172            24           12
AAA     3       105            5            10
BBB     5       40             10           10
BBB     5       60             10           8
```

The objective is to decrease the granularity of `SERVICE_TIME`, `QUEUE_TIME` and `HOLD_TIME`.

To do this, I want to group entries by `EVENT` and `GRADE`, and to estimate average values of `SERVICE_TIME` for a slice window of 60 seconds (i.e. [0;60],[61;120],[121;180],[181;240], and so on till the maximum value of `SERVICE_TIME`). It's important that the slicing window's size can be flexibly changed from 60 to any other value.
So, the slicing should be applied to `SERVICE_TIME`, while other columns `QUEUE_TIME` and `QUEUE_TIME` should be just averaged accordingly.

A sample result:

```
EVENT   GRADE   SERVICE_TIME   QUEUE_TIME   HOLD_TIME
AAA     3       171            22           12
AAA     3       105            5            10
AAA     4       165            15           10
BBB     5       50             10           9
```

So, two values of `SERVICE_TIME`, 170 and 172, were merged because they both belong to the slicing window [121;180]. Therefore I calculated an average `171` and then I just average the corressponding values of `QUEUE_TIME` and `HOLD_TIME`.

How can I do this slicing?

If I had to just calculate an average (without slicing), then I would do it this way.

```
result = df.groupby(['EVENT','GRADE']).agg({'SERVICE_TIME': 'mean', 
                                            'QUEUE_TIME': 'mean', 
                                            'HOLD_TIME': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have the right idea, except that instead of grouping by just `['EVENT','GRADE']`, you'll want to also groupby `SERVICE_GROUP`:

```
df['SERVICE_GROUP'] = (df['SERVICE_TIME']-1)//60
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'EVENT': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
 'GRADE': [3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5],
 'HOLD_TIME': [12, 10, 12, 10, 10, 8],
 'QUEUE_TIME': [20, 15, 24, 5, 10, 10],
 'SERVICE_TIME': [170, 165, 172, 105, 40, 60]})

df['SERVICE_GROUP'] = (df['SERVICE_TIME']-1)//60

result = (df.groupby(['EVENT','GRADE', 'SERVICE_GROUP'])
          .agg({'SERVICE_TIME': 'mean', 
                'QUEUE_TIME': 'mean', 
                'HOLD_TIME': 'mean'}).reset_index())
result = result.drop('SERVICE_GROUP', axis=1)
print(result)
```

prints

```
  EVENT  GRADE  QUEUE_TIME  SERVICE_TIME  HOLD_TIME
0   AAA      3           5           105         10
1   AAA      3          22           171         12
2   AAA      4          15           165         10
3   BBB      5          10            50          9
```

---

The -1 in `(df['SERVICE_TIME']-1)//60` makes 60 part of `SERVICE_GROUP` 0. 
Otherwise, `SERVICE_TIMES` 40 and 60 would not have been grouped together.

Thus `df['SERVICE_GROUP'] = (df['SERVICE_TIME']-1)//60` causes the
`SERVICE_TIME` groups to be the half-open intervals

```
(1, 60], (60, 120], (120, 180], ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new column which divides based on windows(here **'SERVICE_TIME_GROUP'**). And then group using this new column. After grouping you can drop it.

```
WINDOW = 60
df['SERVICE_TIME_GROUP'] = df['SERVICE_TIME'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x==0 else math.ceil(x/(WINDOW*1.0));

result = df.groupby(['EVENT','GRADE','SERVICE_TIME_GROUP']).agg({'SERVICE_TIME': 'mean', 
                                            'QUEUE_TIME': 'mean', 
                                            'HOLD_TIME': 'mean'}).reset_index() 

result = result.drop('SERVICE_TIME_GROUP', 1)
```

For [0;60],[61;120],[121;180],[181;240] , ceil function will work. One special case is 0  which needs to be handled separately. Otherwise just divide by window size and ceil it, you will get a group.

0 = > 1
1-60 => 1
61-120 => 2
121-180 => 3
...